# What is the significance or usage of -1 in this piece of code?

Tags: android, performance, android-intent

```
// Are we charging / charged?

int status = batteryStatus.getIntExtra(BatteryManager.EXTRA_STATUS, -1);

//Determine the Current Battery Level

int level = batteryStatus.getIntExtra(BatteryManager.EXTRA_LEVEL, -1);
int scale = batteryStatus.getIntExtra(BatteryManager.EXTRA_SCALE, -1);
```

ref:http://developer.android.com/training/monitoring-device-state/battery-monitoring.html

Comment: it may be the default value that should be returned if no status is found

Comment: @John: It is indeed the default value. [See `getIntExtra` here](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html)

Comment: that answers your question..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you look at the developer [documentation for this method](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html#getIntExtra(java.lang.String,%20int)), it will tell you:

> **public int getIntExtra (String name, int defaultValue)**
>
> Retrieve extended data from the intent.
>
> **Parameters:**
>
> - ***name*** The name of the desired item.
> - ***defaultValue*** the value to be returned if no value of the desired type is stored with the given name.
>
> **Returns:**
>
> the value of an item that previously added with putExtra() or the
>   default value if none was found.